# How does the entitylink (Wikipedia entity annotator) work in Stanford CoreNLP library? What documentation exists on the underlying methods/data used?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm working on entity extraction for one of my projects and came across CoreNLP. The demo works pretty good, but I can't seem to find any documentation on the entitylink/Wikipedia annotator. Anyone have any sources on what techniques and data were used for these models?

Answer (score 1):

This is based off of Angel Chang's Wikidict resource: http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/crosswikis.pdf , albeit munged a fair bit to allow it to be loaded into memory.